# Text Mining with Chinese Characters in Azure Machine Learning or R Language

Tags: r, text-mining, azure-machine-learning-service

Did anyone know that Text Mining with **Chinese Characters** in Azure Machine Learning or R Language is supported or not?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no official support right now. You would need third party package in r or python, such as [jieba](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jiebaR/README.html) to tokenize your data.